# True last column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So i have this working but some days the data in Column P is blank then the "Last Column" stops at P when actually the last column could be S or T or what ever. Here is what i have so long:

```
Sub trledSCB()

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MItrled").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MItrled").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "836553196"


        lastCol = ActiveSheet.Range("b4").End(xlToRight).Column
    Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("b4", ActiveSheet.Cells(Lastrow, lastCol)).Select

End Sub
```

I hope you guys can help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
LastColumn = sht.Cells(7, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

More about it here: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

This basically does same what your original line does but starting from right to left.

```
Sub trledSCB()

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MItrled").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MItrled").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "836553196"


        lastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(7, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("b4", ActiveSheet.Cells(Lastrow, lastCol)).Select

End Sub
```

By the way, using ActiveSheet is bad practice. Check this: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be how you are selecting your last column.

How you need to change it depends on what you want to count as your Last Column.

- Do you want the last column within the Used range?
- Even if that column only contains blanks?
- Do you want the last column which contains a value within a specific row?

Try this:

```
Dim LastCell As Range

Set LastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                      After:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), _ 
                                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                      LookAt:= xlPart, _ 
                                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _ 
                                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _ 
                                      MatchCase:=False _
                                     )
lastCol = LastCell.Column
```